# Get node offset and length

Tags: php, php-parser

I am using the package [nikic/php-parser](https://packagist.org/packages/nikic/php-parser) to parse a PHP file that is provide by the user. This file will have some PHP functions and I need to know which one are and the exact offset and length of the definition.

**For instance:**

```php
Line | Content
   1 | <?php\n
   2 | function x() { }\n
   3 | x();
```

In this case I have one function called `x`, and the *offset* (where the `function` starts) is *6*, and the *length* is counted until `}`, in this case is *16*.

So I have enabled two attributes on parser: `startFilePos` and `endFilePos`, but for some reason it will not give to me that informations.

Answer (score 0):

**Okay, now I see...**

I am running it like:

```php
$this->parser = (new ParserFactory)->create(ParserFactory::ONLY_PHP7, null, [
    'usedAttributes' => [ 'startFilePos', 'endFilePos' ]
]);
```

But actually the third parameter is not passed to the Lexer as I have expected, and it supports only a deprecated option `throwOnError`.

So I applied it directly to the Lexer:

```php
$this->parser = (new ParserFactory)->create(ParserFactory::ONLY_PHP7, new Lexer([
    'usedAttributes' => [ 'startFilePos', 'endFilePos' ]
]));
```

Now I receives the file offset correctly.